# How do I place images horizontally in a "div" and hide those exceeding the div's width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a slideshow for images.

Images are placed horizontally within the slideshow window.

Only one of them is displayed in the window at a time, while the others are to the right or left of the image and hidden.

Images outside the slideshow window should be hidden because of `overflow = hidden` instead of `display: none` IMO, because I want each image to move in with an animation instead of simply jump out.

Please take a look at https://codepen.io/powerseed/pen/RwJoooQ, where images are placed vertically, while I want horizontally and those outside the `container`'s size should be hidden.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you are at that very beginning of that code with no javascript. I would maybe recommend finding an existing source and learning from that as there are so many out there even basic ones.

Comment: What is exactly the question? How-to create a slideshow tutorial would be a better help here

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the css code in CodePen with something like this can be a very basic setup for a slideshow:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  align-item: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 0;
}


.swiper-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-item: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  animation: slide 3s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
} 

.swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-item: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(-600px);
  }
}
```

The animation is unnecessary as it just showcases the results. Some javascript code can be added if needed to control the slideshow.